# Using random library functions in my own functions python 3

Tags: python, function, random

Why cant I use randrange in this function?

```
import random

print (random.randrange(0,4))

def random(dice):
    dice_one = random.randrange(1,3)
    return (dice_one)


print (random(4))
```

This is the error

```
    line 6, in random
    dice_one = random.randrange(1,3)
    AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'randrange'
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Because you've replaced the module `random` with your own function, also named `random` - why?

Comment: I see, I didnt realise that I would be replacing random. I thought I would be adding to it. I see what i was doing wrong now. Thanks you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python thinks you're trying to call a method of your own random function since you named it the same as the random module. Change your function name to something else and it should be fine.

```
def chance(dice):
    dice_one = random.randrange(1,3)
    return dice_one

print (chance(4))
```

Also, not sure what you're trying to do with the 'dice' argument. If this is meant to be the number of sides on the die, try:

```
def chance(dice):
    dice_one = random.randrange(1,dice)
    return dice_one
```

Answer (score 0):

funny ,actually I am not able to understand which kind of output do you expect but from whatever I have understood the solution of program is this !

```
  import random

  print random.randrange(0,4)

  def random_number(dice):
      dice_one = random.randrange(1,3)
      return dice_one

  print random_number(4)
```